# How to access to node fields in drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-8

I'm having some issues,
I'm loading some nodes and i want to get some values field, this is how is my field

[image]

I'm loading my nodes like this:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type','items', '=')
->execute();
$nodes =  Node::loadMultiple($nids);

foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
  kint($node);
  $array[] = array(
    'name_item_en' => $node->get(field_name_item)->value,
  );
}
```

But i dont know how to get `en` `fr` and `pt` fields values

Could you please help me?
Regards
Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load translation for each language then get corresponding field's value like this:

```php
foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
  $array[] = array(
    'name_item_en' => $node->getTranslation('en')->get('field_name_item')->value,
    'name_item_fr' => $node->getTranslation('fr')->get('field_name_item')->value,
    'name_item_pt' => $node->getTranslation('pt')->get('field_name_item')->value
  );
}
```

If `en` is default language on your site, you may not need to load translation of it:

```php
'name_item_en' => $node->get('field_name_item')->value
```

Comment: Hi Kien i have one issue, getTranslation it's working perfectly with english(en) and spanish(es), but when i use portuguese(pt) and french(fr) i'm getting this error:
InvalidArgumentException: Invalid translation language (fr) specified. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslation() (line 873 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase.php).
Do you have an idea why is happening that?
Regards
Mario

Comment: @skycomputer2 This  [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/262994/102148) might help you out